# Node.js Reverse Proxy/Load Balancer

Tags: node.js, http, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I am checking [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) and [nodejs-proxy](https://github.com/pkrumins/nodejs-proxy) to build a DIY reverse proxy/load balancer in Node.js. After coding a small version, I setup 2 WEBrick servers for the same Rails app so I could load balance (round robin) between them. However each HTTP request is sent to one or another server which is very inefficient since the loading process of CSS and Javascript files from the home page is performed with more than 25 GET requests. 
I tried to play a bit with socket events but I didn't get anywhere because by default it uses keep-alive connections (possibly this is why nginx just support http/1.0). 
Ok, so I am wondering how can my proxy send a block of HTTP requests (for instance loading a webpage entirely, etc) to only one server so I could send the next block to another server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consider stickiness or session persistence. This will ensure future connections after the first connection inbound will get 'stuck' to the chosen server for the duration of the session or until the persistence connection times out.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I checked how some Platform-as-a-Service providers handle that and it seems to be related with sticky sessions.